# Install libtidy with php 5.3.28

Tags: 14.04, php

I have php5.3.28 Installed, I want to install libtidy on the server. I am using command `apt-get install php5-tidy.` This upgraded php 5.3.28 to 5.5.9.

What is the solution to install libtidy with php 5.3.28?

Comment: Add a tag with your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Ok, I think, it's trusty.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install php5-tidy from [precise-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/php5-tidy), but I think that the dependencies for this can not be met on your system.

But you could also try to compile the library itself:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tidy/tidy_20091223cvs.orig.tar.gz
tar xf tidy_20091223cvs.orig.tar.gz
cd tidy-20091223cvs
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```